# Button List Select

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of the button in my flutter app like the picture :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tN8N.png)

and I need to select the container who I'm click on it
for example, change the container color

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the cod you have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use container or button and GestureDetector like below example

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SelectableGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectableGridView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectableGridView> createState() => _SelectableGridViewState();
}

class _SelectableGridViewState extends State<SelectableGridView> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: GridView.builder(
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
          ),
          itemCount: 18,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index;
              }),
              child: Container(
                color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.pink :  Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not sure what your asking exactly, but this may or may not help you:

#### GestureDetector

This will let you respond to clicks on whatever it surrounds, so for example

```
    return
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            //Do something here to respond to a tap on the child Container()
          },
          child: Container(...) /// Your box
```

Now you can do something with it.

Hope this is what you were asking about

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `InkWell` in this following way,

First you have to declare `Color` in your instances and after that you can use it in your `onPress()` widget.

`Color _colorContainer = Colors.blue;`

Now you can use it in your widget as follow:

```
         Ink(
            child: InkWell(
            child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: _colorContainer ,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _colorContainer = _colorContainer == Colors.red ? 
                    Colors.blue : 
                    Colors.red;
            });
          },
        )),
```